# Gradle messing up IntelliJ project structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I've built up a gradle project for my war. I set up the project structure accordingly, manually (through the project structure interface). However when I do a full gradle refresh (for renewing dependencies etc) gradle goes ahead and changes my project structure for some reason. One thing it does is change the target of my `resources` from `src/main/resources` to `build/resources`. Other things it does is remove my `jboss deployment descriptor` and also messes up my `war` deployment which I set up to contain the `war:exploded` artifact but instead it goes on and puts the content that is inside the `war:exploded` artifact instead of putting the artifact itself. I'm guessing this has to do with some settings i've configured in the `build.gradle` file but I'm not really sure what it is...

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply from: 'config.gradle', to: project

group 'com.company'
version '2.2'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    randomVariable = ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'customURL' }
    maven { url 'customURL2' }
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir 'src/main/java'
    main.resources.srcDir 'src/main/resources'
}
dependencies {...}
```

This is how my build.gradle file is set up. Also I've got some tasks defined but I'm not running them. I just do `Refresh all Gradle projects` from intellij UI..

Comment: What versions of Gradle and Intellij are you using?

Comment: intellij 15. I don't have gradle installed on my computer I just use the intellij wrapper.